# How to get an interpolation weight from a mathematical definition

Tags: interpolation, numpy

It was recently explained to me that a "Nearest neighbor" kernel for 1D interpolation can be implemented like this using NumPy

```
def nearest(delta):
    delta = abs(delta)
    if delta <= 0.5:
        return numpy.asarray([0,1])
    else:
return numpy.asarray([1,0])
```

Whereas the mathematical definition of nearest neighbor is

$h_{nn}(\delta) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if}& -0.5 \le \delta < 0.5 \\
0 & otherwise \\
\end{cases}
$

Similarly linear interpolation, which in NumPy can be expressed as

```
def linear(delta):
    delta = abs(delta)
return [delta,1-delta]
```

But the mathematical definition for it goes

$h_{lin}(\delta) = 
\begin{cases}
1-|\delta| &\text{if}&  0 \le |\delta| < 1 \\
0 & \text{if}& 1 \le |\delta|
\end{cases}
$

My question is how to form a kernel with weights out of these mathematical definitions, as the code belonging to them does not paint the same picture that the mathematical definitions paint.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question but think about this: nearest neighbor rounding is done by adding 1/2 the interval (I presume delta), and rounding down.  Try it by hand to see it, then the algorithm should be equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give a concrete example. Let's say you have a signal that was sampled every second. The frequency is $f = \frac{1}{1} = 1 Hz$.

Time: $T = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 2 & 3\end{bmatrix}$

Value: $X = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4\end{bmatrix}$

We want to increase the frequency by $2$ i.e. $2 Hz$ (sample every 0.5 seconds).

Time: $\tilde{T} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0.5 & 1 & 1.5 & 2 & 2.5 & 3\end{bmatrix}$

Value: $\tilde{X} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & x_1 & 2 & x_2 & 3 & x_3 & 4\end{bmatrix}$

$x_1, x_2, x_3$ is determined by your interpolation functions $h_{nn}(\delta)$ and $h_{lin}(\delta)$. Here $\delta$ is time and both functions define intervals. Each value is given by $S(\delta) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} X_i \cdot h_{nn}(\delta-i)$. For nearest neighbor change the interval to $0 \leq \delta < 1$. Then $S(0) = S(0.5) = X_0 \cdot 1 + X_1 \cdot 0 + \cdots = X_0$. See also [Cardinal B-splines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline#Cardinal_B-spline).

While downsampling by $M$ requires strided convolution $$y[n] = \sum_k x[nM - k]h[k]$$

Upsampling needs fractionally strided convolution which is also called transposed convolution (see [stackexchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/49299/what-is-fractionally-strided-convolution-layer))

$$y[j + nM] = \sum_k x[n-k]h[j+kM] \text{ and } j = 0, \dots, M-1$$

Transposed convolution with kernel size 3, stride 2 and padding 1 is equivalent to inserting 1 zero between inputs, pad by 1 and stride 1.

The kernel is $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ or $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ (either cross correlation or convolution) for nearest-neighbor interpolation (to double frequency):

```
from torch.nn import ConvTranspose1d
import torch
import numpy as np

def interpolate_nn(X):
  X = torch.from_numpy(X)
  with torch.no_grad():
    op = ConvTranspose1d(in_channels=1, out_channels=1,
                         kernel_size=3, stride=2,
                         bias=False, dilation=1, padding=1)
    op.weight.data = torch.tensor([0, 1, 1]).view(1, 1, -1).float()

    return op(X.view(1, 1, -1).float()).numpy().flatten()

X = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
print(interpolate_nn(X))
```

The result is [1. 1. 2. 2. 3. 3. 4.]

For linear interpolation use $\begin{bmatrix}0.5 & 1 & 0.5\end{bmatrix}$. The result is [1.  1.5 2.  2.5 3.  3.5 4. ]

Compare it with your $h_{lin}(\delta)$:

$\begin{align*}
S(0) &= X_0h_{lin}(0 - 0) + X_1h_{lin}(0 - 1) + \cdots = X_0(1 - |0|) = X_0\\
S(0.5) &= X_0h_{lin}(0.5 - 0) + X_1h_{lin}(0.5 - 1) + \cdots = 0.5X_0 + 0.5X_1\\
S(1) &= X_0h_{lin}(1 - 0) + X_1h_{lin}(1 - 1) + \cdots = 1X_1\\
\vdots
\end{align*}$